# Number of Javascript lines executed during page load

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, profiler

I have an use case where I need to get the total number of Javascript lines executed when my web page is loading.

The problem I am facing is that the browser throws an alert when a certain number of JS execution exceed ( 5 million I think in case of IE ) and the page gets hanged.

I used the profiler available in IE Developers tool bar,but it gives me the total number of JS functions called but not the total number/count of lines executed.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I highly doubt that this is based on lines of code. It most likely triggers when the JS engine takes too much time without passing control back to the browser.

Comment: `while (true) ;` will also cause the page to hang... get what I'm saying?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I would have thought the same thing, but interestingly, it appears the OP is actually correct: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2008/09/23/a-script-on-this-page-is-causing-internet-explorer-to-run-slowly-if-it-continues-to-run-your-computer-may-become-unresponsive.aspx

Comment: I was able to solve this issue in my machine by making the number of lines inifinite from 5 million by editing the registry,but thats not possible for everyone who use my web page.Is there any tool which tell me the number of lines ?

Comment: You're doing something terribly wrong here.

Comment: Instead of working around the issue, I'd invest that time in refactoring. 5mil statements is a lot for any webpage. Not even facebook, with all the Ajax going on, gets in to the millions.

Comment: From what I understand, it's 5 million statements *without* handing the control back to the browser, so there's definitely some room for refactoring :)

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

http://www-archive.mozilla.org/performance/jsprofiler.html

> The first line specifies the js file from which times were gathered.
>   Each line below that is of the format:   [A, B] C {D-E} F {G, H, I}

D -> Base line number of the function in the JS file 
E -> Extent (last) line number of the function in the JS file

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should really redesign your code; 5 million statements without handing control back to the browser is by all means a lot of code, imagine how mobile browsers will struggle with it.

One way to find out how many statements are executed is by instrumenting your code, adding one statement for each statement in your code to count the number of times it was executed, effectively doubling up the number of statements in your code.

There are also code coverage tools that can run inside the browser without having to instrument your code at all; Googling for "javascript code coverage" gives a fair amount of browser extensions that you could use, such as [hrtimer](http://hrtimer.mozdev.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Just split it into smaller chunks and call after a timeout - that gets around the IE issue.  e.g.

```
somethingBig();
somethingElseBig();
```

instead write :

```
somethingBig();
setTimeout(somethingElseBig);
```

Answer (score 0):

In BASH:

```
wc -l file.js
```

In PHP:

```
<?php
$c=0;
$file_handle = fopen("file.js", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line = fgets($file_handle);
    $c++;
}
fclose($file_handle);
print "$c lines.\n";
?>
```

In Node.js:

```
var i, count = 0, js=require('fs').createReadStream('file.js');

js.on('data', function(chunk) {
    for (i=0; i < chunk.length; ++i)
        if (chunk[i] == 10) count++;
});

js.on('end', function() {
    console.log(count);
});
```

Try [minification](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) to get your line-numbers down.

This seems like a terrible-lot of code, though.

Comment: That won't do it.  IE is counting statements executed (not lines of code), so statements inside of loops are counted on each iteration, etc. This is stated in the [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2008/09/23/a-script-on-this-page-is-causing-internet-explorer-to-run-slowly-if-it-continues-to-run-your-computer-may-become-unresponsive.aspx) mellamokb provided in his comment on the question.

Comment: Yeh, I was answering their original question, but the correct answer is "rewrite your code, it's too much code."