# How do I write a recursive blocking function in JavaScript without overflowing the stack?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

Thanks for looking.

## Background

I am writing a JavaScript-heavy app for a client and have a need for a utility function to which I can pass a condition and a call back function.  If the condition is not met, I need to wait a few milliseconds and then test again.  If the condition is met, then execute the call back.

## What I have so far

I have written this method as part of a utility class:

```
 ThreadLocker: function (condition, callback) {
        //If condition is true then it resumes running code
        if (condition()) {
            callback();
        } else { //Else it waits 10ms and tries again
            setTimeout(Util.ThreadLocker(condition,callback), 10);
        }
    }
```

Here is how it is used:

```
   var condition = function(){return (myGlobalVariable == "foo") ? true : false;};
   var callback = function(){alert("Ready to rock!");};

    Util.Threadlocker(condition,callback);
```

## Problem

Even if I set the timeout period to 10 *seconds*, I get an immediate stack overflow.  Here is what Chrome gives me:

"Maximum call stack size exceeded."

And if you look at the stack, it looks like the function was called several dozens of times in a millisecond or two EVEN IF the setTimeOut was set to 10 seconds.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
setTimeout(Util.ThreadLocker(condition,callback), 10);
```

calls directly your 'ThreadLocker' function, there is no timeout set. Try

```
setTimeout(function () { Util.ThreadLocker(condition,callback); }, 10);
```

You may also need to know, that javaScript isn't multi threaded. It simply dispatches your function after n ms, or as soon as nothing else is executed. Same for intervals, if you create an interval of 10ms: the task needs 30ms, it gets executed in the 10th ms, and then in the 40th ms from start (immediately after the first task has finished).

So you can't really lock, but also nothing else can race your code.

As for stack overflow: If you really have the case, eg. a recursive function that may overflow the stack of 5 million lines (in IE, [Number of Javascript lines executed during page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364177/number-of-javascript-lines-executed-during-page-load)), you can defer a function using a timeout of 0:

```
setTimeout(function () { }, 0);
```

That's also the way underscore's [defer](http://underscorejs.org/#defer) works.

Comment: Thank you sir (or ma'am)!  Worked beautifully!